# Apps are muted on my iPad

Tags: ipad, applications, audio

I have a 1st generation iPad and it is doing a very strange thing. All the installed 3rd party apps are muted. Video and music playback works and audio is ok, but all other Apps are muted.

Why is this happening? What can I do about it?

Comment: Are you sure that the little switch on the upper right of your iPad is not in the mute position ?

Comment: The switch is not muting the iPad, I can listen music with the built in iTunes app. It seems that only third party apps are muted somehow!

Comment: How does the iPad's behavior change when the switch is in the position opposite the one it is currently in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out finally. It had to do with the hardware switch on the side of the iPad was set to rotation mode.

When I changed back this hardware switch to function as the mute switch then I could un-muted my iPad and all apps started to function normally. Then I could change back the hardware switch to become the rotation lock-unlock switch.